# using namespace std and Template Classes

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I can now see why it would be bad practice to include

```
using namespace std;
```

in header files for a project.  I have heard that including this directive in private .cpp function definition files is not so much of a problem, since they are usually not directly included in main().  Is there an exception here for templated classes, which usually have to include the .cpp definition files to compile and run correctly (unless you include the definitions directly in the header file)?

So, would the general rules be:

1) Don't use using namespace std in header files.
2 ) It's okay to use it in private .cpp definition files, unless the definitions are for templated classes.

Comment: define the template in the header file, and use (e.g) `std::string` throughout the file.

Comment: Okay.  Does that mean it is not so much frowned upon if you use the std namespace in private .cpp files?  Or could this cause issues if new functions are released for some libraries that conflict with functions defined in other namespaces that are included?

Comment: Changes in third party include files (or even in your own include files) may introduce conflicts after a "using namespace" however these conflicts will be isolated to a single cpp file and therefore much easier to diagnose than they would be if "using namespace" in a Module A header triggered a conflict in module B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule I use is "Do not use "using namespace" or a namespace alias in any file intended to be the target of a #include."

Also as a general rule, "using namespace" or a namespace alias should appear after all #includes in a file.

Comment: Nice.  I'll adopt that.

Comment: +1 for the bit on using statements *after* include files